# Let's encrypt установить SSL через Snap

Tags: ubuntu, apache, ssl, letsencrypt, certbot

Ubuntu-16.04-x86_64, Apache/2.4.18

Попытался установить SSL от Let's encrypt так, как делал это раньше, через

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -dexample.com
```

но получил ошибку:

> Skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system.
> Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore. Certbot cannot
> be installed. Please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other
> alternatives.

погуглил, и, если правильно понял [из этого обсуждения на git](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/8535), certbot-auto больше не поддерживается.

Новым способом установки сертификата [Предлагается snapd](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache)

Вроде как получилось установить его через комманды:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install snapd
```

однако попытка установки certbot

```
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

приводит к очередной ошибке:

```
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-059174937: mount failed: Unknown error -1
```

На этом шаге я окончательно запутался и не понимаю, в чем дело и куда двигаться.

Comment: Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore.
Certbot cannot be installed.
Please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other alternatives.
Совет не работает в 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, нужно просто вручную установить certbot:

```
sudo apt install certbot python-certbot-apache
```

а затем установить сертификат для домена:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d example.com
```

letsencrypt-auto, на данный момент, не поддерживается (скорее всего, навсегда, как можно понять из чата на git по ссылке в вопросе)

Comment: Его как года 3 на debian нет :)

Comment: @mik.ov на апаче был, поэтому при попытке установки ssl на новый домен, столкнулся с сюрпризом)